# preg_match UTF-8 issue

Tags: php, preg-match

`preg_match("/\b(word1|word2)\b/iu", 'text text text word1 text text');`

For some reason the above code doesn't work with Hebrew characters on one server, but does work on another one. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have perl compatible regular expressions (PCRE) with unicode properties support enabled? that would be my guess.

Comment: To find out, at your shell - type `pcretest -C` and it will tell you if you have unicode properties support enabled.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but how would I check this on a Windows WAMP installation?

Answer (score 0):

You need Perl Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE) version 3.9 at least on your server to be able to have UTF-8 characters in pattern with `preg_match()` function

Answer (score -1):

try preg_match("/\b(word1|word2)\b/iu", utf8_decode('text text text word1 text text'));